# Which software for high quality e-newsletter in decent file size

Tags: software-recommendation, file-size, graphic-styles, newsletter

I design an e-newsletter with graphics and text. I have been using non-professional tools up until now (layout and design in Publisher with picture editing in basic picture editor) to create a very professional newsletter. I know it's not ideal. I then print it to PDF form and send it as an attachment to be viewed largely by people with no further internet access. Sometimes it's a pain but I've learned to work with most glitches.

Now that we're receiving more high color ads, the file sizes in the final PDF ate getting way too large! To compress the images compromises quality more than we can allow.

Ideally not a large investment but I'll hear them!

Comment: You *might* find that merely changing the PDF output settings (job options) result in smaller PDF sizes. It *could* be a simple matter of needing Acrobat to better solidify the PDFs themselves rather than purchasing and learning a new layout application. Ultimately whatever you use will still be outputting PDFs based on your description of the workflow. What file sizes are you seeing that are problematic?

Comment: attachment to what? to e-mail? no further internet access means what? no web-browser, just an e-mail client for your readers?? if your readers are in rural places and your advertising customers are providing way to fancy content, then you got a conceptual problem, not just a technical file-size problem. Have you defined (or done tests) what a "decent" file size is? I work in Africa and constantly have bandwidth problems, but indeed it can be solved if the system is healthy all around - tell more detail; could your ad-providers for example give you eps? color is not automatically much more data

Answer (score 2):

InDesign (paid) or Scribus (free) can export to PDF and you can control the level of compression for any included images. Generally the more pictures you add and the higher their resolution, the resulting PDF will grow in size. You just need to find the right balance between compression and file size.